Installation source and Software selection error for Oracle Linux 8 unattended install
I am attempting an unattended installation of Oracle Linux 8, but I am stuck with error on Installation Source and Software Selection.
 ================================================================================[0m
 ================================================================================[0m
 Installation[0m
 1) [x] Language settings                 2) [x] Time settings[0m
        (English (United States))                (America/New_York timezone)[0m
 3) [!] Installation source               4) [!] Software selection[0m
        (Error setting up software               (Error checking software[0m
        source)                                  selection)[0m
 5) [x] Installation Destination          6) [x] Kdump[0m
        (Automatic partitioning                  (Kdump is enabled)[0m
        selected)[0m
 7) [x] Network configuration[0m
        (Wired (ens2) connected)[0m
 The installation was stopped due to an error which occurred while running in non-interactive cmdline mode. Since there cannot be any questions in cmdline mode, edit your kickstart file and retry installation.[0m

I have the following kicstart file:
#version=OL8
%packages
@^minimal-environment
kexec-tools

%end
# Installation mode
install
text

# Automated commandline install
bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=vda

# Root Password Settings
rootpw --iscrypted <redacted>
sshpw --username=packer packer
# User
user --name=<redacted> --uid=400 --gid=400 --groups=wheel
sshkey --username=<redacted> "<redacted>"

# Host configurations
selinux --permissive
services --disabled="kdump" --enabled="NetworkManager,sshd,rsyslog,chronyd,cloud-init,cloud-init-local,cloud-config,cloud-final,rngd"
timezone UTC --isUtc

# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=link --activate --onboot=yes
network  --hostname=localhost.localdomain

# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --disabled

ignoredisk --only-use=vda
autopart
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel

# System timezone
timezone America/New_York --isUtc

%addon com_redhat_kdump --enable --reserve-mb='auto'

%end

%anaconda
pwpolicy root --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
pwpolicy user --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --emptyok
pwpolicy luks --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
%end

Can anyone give me a hint on what is wrong? I have been stuck here for some time.

If my post answers your question, please consider marking it as accepted. This helps with future searches on the same topic (and gives me more reputation).

You need to define the repos in your kickstart file. Add lines
repo --name="ol_baseos_latest" --baseurl="https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/x86_64"
repo --name="appstream" --baseurl="https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/appstream/x86_64"

along with any other repositories you plan to pull packages from.

Thanks for your answer, but I tried adding the lines proposed into my kickstart file and the same error output was returned.
